# compile and run f# scripts from osx terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, f#, mono

Is there a way to compile and run f# from osx console? I have mono installed and added `/mono64/bin/mono` to paths, but `mcs` command returns

```
test.fs(2,0): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `let'
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### FSharp Interactive:

> fsharpi

F# Interactive for F# 4.0 (Open Source Edition)
Freely distributed under the Apache 2.0 Open Source License

For help type #help;;

#### FSharp Compiler:

> fsharpc

F# Compiler for F# 4.0 (Open Source Edition)
Freely distributed under the Apache 2.0 Open Source License